# How to use chunking to reduce file size

Tags: pandas, memory, memory-management, chunks, chunking

I'm trying to read a ~2.3 GB file that exceeds the RAM of my hardware. I want to apply chunking to read this file.

I tried `chunksize` of `10**2`, `10**3`, `10**4`, and `10**5` but all still exceed the RAM limit.

What I want to do with the file:
Keep all the rows and extensively manipulate the pandas dataframe, mainly using numpy.

```
import pandas as pd

meth_450_kipan = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t", chunksize=10**5):
    meth_450_kipan = pd.concat([meth_450_kipan, chunk], ignore_index=True)
meth_450_kipan
```

Comment: At the end, your dataframe will be fully loaded into memory. Chunks are useful only if you reduce the size of dataframe at each iteration. The worst here is `pd.concat` at each iteration. A good practice is to collect data in python structure (dict or list) then concatenate once at the end.

Comment: @Corralien mind to show the solution/example?

Comment: I have no solution if you want to keep all rows. What do you want to do with your dataframe?

Comment: the idea with chunking is that you operate on your data iteratively. you should work on processing/reducing/writing/uploading/etc *on each chunk* so that you never have the full dataframe in memory at the same time. chunking doesn't just magically give you more memory - if your data is too big to fit into memory at once, you can't fit it into memory at once, end of story. so you need to restructure your workflow to work on the data iteratively, hence Corralien's question of what you want to do next.

Comment: I need to keep all the rows and I want to perform extensive data manipulation using numpy etc.

Comment: Each row can be processed separately from other? Or do you need to group some rows together before processing (like `groupby`)? How many columns do you have? If many, are they all useful in the same time?

Comment: If it's mostly `numpy`, is this something you can do directly in `numpy` with something like `numpy.loadtxt`?